# acrobat reader get error while reading document, it might be corrupted and can't be repaired

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, acrobat

I can't open [this pdf file](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1soL1XMx3yqMxwMqBGGChpEyf-IjpM9q2&export=download) on acrobat reader it tell me error (in french) without code error. How can I get more information about error alert when opne pdf file in acrobat reader, is there shortcut to show more info about error because currently it only say in french :

> "error occured reading document, it might be corrupred and cant be
>   repaired"

In chrome pdf viewer I can open this error-original.pdf

PS: here is another [ok-original.pdf](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1t5Ibfy1CHILc-5ZnGSSNArGw-Dgcwv2l&export=download) which works when opening with acrobat reader.

Im on windows10, acrobat reader Version : 19.10.20098.316574

I can't explain why my file error-original.pdf is corruped maybe after some manipulation with pdfbox but cant reproduce. My question is how getting more error info about this error.

### UPDATE #1 (more info)

Here is code I use to prepare/manipulate my original.pdf 
This code do 4 things:
1. set partialName of a field (same like current field value)
2. remove all links in pages
3. remove field with empty||blank value
4. temporary compress to try to gain some octet by chance using @mkl method [OptimizeAfterMerge.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/merge/OptimizeAfterMerge.java#L109)

```
Document pdfOriginal = PDDocument.load(f.toFile());

//1.set field partialName like his current value
pdfOriginal.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields().forEach(field -> {
    if (field instanceof PDTextField && !field.getValueAsString().contains("--")
            && !field.getValueAsString().isBlank() && !field.getValueAsString().isEmpty()) {
        field.setPartialName(field.getValueAsString());
    }
});

//2.remove all link in document
removeLinksInPages(pdfOriginal);

//3.remove field with empty||blank value
pdfOriginal.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields().forEach(field -> {
    if (field instanceof PDTextField
            && (field.getValueAsString().isBlank() || field.getValueAsString().isEmpty())) {
        try {
            removeField(pdfOriginal, field.getPartialName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

pdfOriginal.save(new File(f.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
pdfOriginal.close();

//4.try to compress to gain some octets
PDDocument compress = PDDocument.load(f.toFile());
OptimizePdfDocument.optimize(compress);
compress.save(new File(f.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
compress.close();
```

Method used:

[removeLinksInPages(...)](https://pastebin.com/RfGtFRr5)

[removeField(...)](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/RemoveField.java#L172)

N.B. I can't confirm this code always output correupted file because it wont, but  sometimes if I open file with acrobat reader it can't be read.

(message to @mkl : believe me, im not telling one of your method corrupt file here, and im aware of that your compression is for merged file dont worry, i certainly doing thing in wrong way and try to find problem, thank for understanding)

### UPDATE #2 (weird result)

I run into weird thing: just by running this pdfbox code on [the above corrupted file error-original.pdf](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1soL1XMx3yqMxwMqBGGChpEyf-IjpM9q2&export=download) :

```
PDDocument pdfOriginal = PDDocument.load(new File(".../error-original.pdf"));
pdfOriginal.save(new File(".../error-original.pdf"));
pdfOriginal.close();
```

Acrobat Reader is able to open outputed (untouched pdf file) but when you scroll acrobat reader get another error : "this page has error, acrobat reader can't show this page. contact pdf author to resolve problem" and when I close error-alert-popup I can continue to scroll and read my pdf. 
You can try to open with acrobat reader this [error-on-scroll.pdf](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1apz69EoMqJAFmvXyMREWnVAceWTQWGhW&export=download)

ps: message to @acrobatreader : the problem is I AM PDF AUTHOR and I don't know how to resolve (joke)

@KenS can you please give some input with this, it seems error is on page2

Comment: **A)** Please share the original PDF. **B)** Furthermore, you say the code does only sometimes damage the PDF. This usually means that there is another external factor you have not identified. E.g. do you sometimes still have the file opened in some other program while running the code?

Comment: **C)** This *weird thing* is not so weird after all: PDFBox during the load of the document runs into a similar problem as Adobe Reader but then attempts to read the file in a different manner, ignoring cross reference streams but searching objects instead. When saving it, it does so correctly as far as the xref start positions are concerned. Thus, Adobe Reader can load the output. Unfortunately, though, enough other stuff is damaged in the file to have Adobe Reader run into different errors later.

Comment: **A)** working file is listed above here you are [ok-original.pdf](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1t5Ibfy1CHILc-5ZnGSSNArGw-Dgcwv2l&export=download)  **B)** you are right I cant identify the problem to reproduce and understand why in my folder when I open file I run into error. And I think NO file was not open because when I open it I can't make pddocument.save() to same filename (by replacing because file is open)

Comment: The content stream for page 2 of error-on-scroll-acrobatreader.pdf has a token 7.3roce77. This is not a valid number, its not a name, and its not a PDF operator, so PDF consumers will probably ignore it and hope nothing breaks. I imagine this is what Acrobat is complaining about. There is also a zlib error decompressing object 70 in the file.(invalid distance, too far back) Note; that's the Flate compressed content stream for page 2, so its probably related. If I understand you correctly, then I agree with mkl, editing a broken file is just going to make it worse.

Comment: bee: Ah, ok-original.pdf is the file you started with? Ok. Nonetheless, as a corollary of @KenS's answer it is clear that (at least the worst) damage happened ***after** the file had been processed by PDFBox **and** by Adobe Acrobat*. I'll explain in an answer (it does not fit into comments) but you can start reviewing your setup for PDF processors which handled the PDF after PDFBox and Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 1):

When Acrobat displays an error you can try holding down the control key (on Windows) while left clicking the 'OK' button. This sometimes gives you more information.

In this case it doesn't. The file is badly broken. It has been edited at least twice and edits look to have broken the file beyond simple repair. The file contains:

```
startxref
81612
```

which should point to the start of the xref table (which contains the offset in the file of all the objects). Instead the file offset points to:

```
C89E1E8B69>]/Index[4 2 10 1 156 2]/Info 5 0 R/Length 31/Prev 77185/Root 1 0 R/Size 158/Type/XRef/W[1 3 0]>>stream
```

which is part of the way through the cross-reference stream. The trailer dictionary contains a /Prev entry which should point to the previous xref, instead, again, it points to part way through the dictioanry for the xref stream. Correcting that, it then points to a trailer dictionary which, yet again, has a /Prev entry which is incorrect.

Whatever you are using to edit this file, it keeps on breaking it in the same way.

I can fix these offsets, which allows Ghostscript to open and read the file (MuPDF is capable of repairing even the original file). It still complains that the xref is invalid, and attempts a repair. During the repair it finds that some PDF objects have the same object number and generation number, which should not be the case.

Since Acrobat won't open the repaired file, it may be that this is what Acrobat is complaining about as well. It appears that both times the file has been edited it has included new definitions of objects 4, 5 and 10, but has not incremented their generation numbers leaving them at 0, and therefore duplicates of each other.

Fundamentally, if Acrobat won't open your file you should regard it as totally broken.

Comment: thank you for anwser, it seems a little bit technical to me. How you analyse this pdf to get this infos ? I want understand what going on but seems out of scope to me, i cant even say how I produced this file. I tried to edit ok-original.pdf in acrobat reader (udpating field value then resave/replace) It always works.

Comment: I used a number of different tools, and also simply opened the PDF file in a hex editor and looked at the contents, calculating the correct offsets of the /Prev and startxref values by looking at the hex values of the offsets in the file. Given sufficient familiarity with the PDF specification its tedious but not hard to work out what the problem(s) are. Since you say you are using pdfbox you should probably report the problems there.

Comment: I updated my question if you can check please...  I have also tagged my question with "pdfbox" do you advice me to remove tags pdf and acrobat and just leave pdfbox here ?

Comment: I'd leave all the tags, they all seem reasonable to me

Answer (score 0):

*A corollary to [Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474700/1729265)...*

There are three revisions in your file (i.e. your file has an initial version and two incremental updates). As your PDFBox code only saves as completely new file, not using an incremental update, the end result of your PDFBox code is already in that first revision.

Furthermore, your original file "ok-original.pdf", is saved using cross reference tables while all revisions in your result file only use cross reference streams.

As your PDFBox code saves files using the same cross references technique as it has loaded them with (PDFBox default), this implies that even the first revision is not the immediate output of PDFBox but that output loaded and stored again by some other program, probably Adobe Acrobat, which switched the technique.

Thus, you don't see the exact PDFBox output anymore, not even in the initial revision, but only what the next program made out of it. So in particular PDFBox is not responsible for building the cross references offsets in the cross reference streams and also not for the offset of these cross reference streams themselves.

As KenS has already explained in his answer, the offsets of the cross reference stream objects in **startxref** and **Prev** entries are too large; more exactly, they are too large by 116 for the initial revision, by 122 for the second one, and by 131 for the final one, the complete PDF.

PDFBox (see above) has not created these cross reference streams, let alone their offset values. Thus, your PDFBox code is not responsible for the wrong offsets!

If Adobe Acrobat is the program which has generated these three revisions, I would also doubt that Adobe Acrobat has caused the wrong offsets.

To me it appears like afterwards the file has been copied or transferred by some program or via some channel that dropped some bytes from the file, 116 bytes in the first revision, 6 bytes in the second, and 9 bytes in the third.

(This dropping might also have happened as a result of a merger of multiple bytes into fewer ones...)

Comment: do you want me accepting your answer? Because even if it is too technical to me it doesn’t mean you and KenS are wrong. By the way to understand concept like revision, versions, incremental update, cross reference table, streams and offsets; sratrtxref and Prev... what are your mkl and @KenS recommendation to learn this? Do you have please some good ressources video? Tutorial? to geeting started? I prefer avoid starting with pdf specification doc which is not easy to start. Would be awesome to find some  pdf-under-the-hood tutorial ^^  apologize my ignorance and thank you for help

Comment: You can accept either one, KenS did the first analysis, I did the interpretation for you. By the way, have you determined what piece of software eventually damaged your files?

Comment: i didnt and can’t reproduce what i can say i use pdfbox, acrobat reader dc (replacing/saving after update field value) in addition of this I use pdfescape (free online webapp) unlock fields and move resize change partialName then download file. That is complet scenario i am using for manipulation this original.pdf with. Would love find error or reproduce it. By the way after reading things on wikipedia i understand there is no video-courses to learn pdf structure indeepth the only one exist is pdf spec on top of ISO’s one? Dammage i cant find on web other tutorial easily like java learning

Comment: @bee Concerning tutorials... there are some here and there on the web. E.g. the are some in the blogs of idr solutions [here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/01/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-bugs-gotchas-and-tips/). To really understand the internals, though, you'll have to study the pdf specification plus a number of other specifications referenced from it.

Comment: @bee Ah, the actual main index of the idr solutions PDF tutorials is [this](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/series-article-index/). The [link given above](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/01/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-bugs-gotchas-and-tips/) is only the subsection "Bugs, Gotchas and Tips"...

Comment: thank you  a lot will check it asap. I just start with [pdf-tools whitepapers](https://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf20/en/resources/pdf-iso-standards/) especially starting with this starting [whitepaper](https://www.pdf-tools.com/public/downloads/whitepapers/whitepaper-pdf-primer-en.pdf) and will consider your links thank you

Comment: There are also a few good articles on PDF by "Raul", like this one: https://edwardsnowden.com/docs/doc/2004-12-09-SIDToday-Ask-Raul-PDF-Files.pdf

Comment: I'd accept this answer, not mine. There's tons more information here, along with the highly useful notes about the behaviour of PDFBox and why it cannot possibly have caused the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `error-original.pdf` pdf has /Prev in addition to `ok-original.pdf`

But I reproduced and find solution:
Problem here is GIT, in my project when getting file from remote it seems treat pdf file like text instead binary. After just adding .gitattributes file with content `*.pdf  binary` resolve the problem. 
So to resume:

1. Pdf author (on his local machine) has working pdf.
2. pdf author commit + push to remote.
3. Another user pull changes from remote and try to open pdf: it result in "corrupted file".
4. adding .gittattributes at .gitignore level fix problem.

PS:But all things @mkl and Kens said above stay correct too.